# Get web page that threw the last error in Global.asax Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a large asp.net project and we're getting some exceptions, trouble is we don't know what circumstances they're being thrown, I'd like to store a link to the page that threw the error along with the stack trace.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Context.Request.Url
```

Comment: You may have my babies.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

You need [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).  It's very easy to add to your application, and can log all your exception sources and details to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest no-nonsense option would be to use ASP.NET healthmonitoring. You shall get all the info you would need about the what-when-where-how of an exception.